# Is it a convenient way to write longer program codes in LaTeX?

Tags: conditionals, programming, loops, random-numbers, data-structures

Before I only used `ifthenelse` and `for` loops, but not complicated data structures. I don't know what is the convenient way to write longer codes.

As an example I would like to generate a random permutation of numbers from 0 to 9. This is not a complicated problem, but I do not know how to solve it easily. Are there any package which makes programming comfortable?

Comment: Hmmm... comfortable... subjective much? I think you also need to be very specific in terms of the question, which is currently somewhat vague, and show how you would solve this "[non-] complicated problem".

Comment: `pgffor`, `etoolbox` etc. A lot of packages exist actually for 'programming'.

Comment: [Pythontex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) and [sagetex](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) let you program in Python.

Comment: please, can you mention more? (pgffor, etoolbox, luacode, ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With LuaTeX you can use the script language Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function permute(n)
  local tab = {}
  for i = 1, n do tab[i] = i end
  for i = 1, n do
    local j = math.random(i, n)
    tab[i], tab[j] = tab[j], tab[i]
  end
  for i = 1, n do
    tex.print("\\shortstack{"..i.."\\\\"..tostring(tab[i]).."} ")
  end
end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\directlua{permute(20)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LuaTeX is not a simple package, as I see. I need a package, not an engine, which has to be installed.

Comment: I need something like LuaTeX in which I do not need to use backslash before each command, and it is very general (with functions, structures, recursions, etc.) but I would like to use only a package, is it possible?

Answer (score 12):

Here's an implementation of the [Knuth shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation#Knuth_shuffles) with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\input{random}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_eq:NN \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \setrannum

\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
\int_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_random_int
\prop_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop
\prop_new:N \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop % the identity
\seq_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq

\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 100 }
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop { #1 } { #1 }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand{\generatepermutation}{m}
 {
  \knuthshuffle_generate:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printpermutation}{}
 {
  \left(
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq }
   {
    \begin{array}{c}
    ##1 \\ \seq_item:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { ##1 }
    \end{array}
   }
  \right)
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n
 {
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { -1 } { 2 }
   {
    \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \l_knuthshuffle_random_int { 1 } { ##1 }
    \prop_get:NnN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl 
    \prop_get:NVN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl 
    \prop_put:NnV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
    \prop_put:NVV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
     {
      \prop_item:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 }
     }
   }
  %\seq_show:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq % for debugging
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\generatepermutation{20}

\[
\printpermutation
\]

\end{document}
```

The permutation is stored in a sequence, then it's up to you what to do with it. I added a `\printpermutation` macro just to show how to print the most recently generated permutation.

[image]

The tools I use are

1. A fixed property list representing the identity permutation on the numbers from 1 to 1000
2. A loop from the last place downward; at step *k*, a random number *r* between 1 and *k* is generated thanks to `random.tex` by D. Arsenau (let's hope it's integrated soon in `expl3`); the element at place *k* is swapped with the element at place *r*;
3. Another loop loads a sequence with the so determined elements, for further processing.

The identity is defined up to 100, which should be a sufficient bound and keeps processing time down.

---

There is a faster way (which wastes more memory, though), using a `\csname` trick. The previous solution was in the spirit of showing the available tools with a toy problem, rather than looking for an efficient implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\input{random}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_eq:NN \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \setrannum

\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
\int_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_random_int
\seq_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\generatepermutation}{m}
 {
  \knuthshuffle_generate:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printpermutation}{}
 {
  \left(
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \seq_count:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq }
   {
    \begin{array}{c}
    ##1 \\ \seq_item:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { ##1 }
    \end{array}
   }
  \right)
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl } { ##1 }
   }
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { -1 } { 2 }
   {
    \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \l_knuthshuffle_random_int { 1 } { ##1 }
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
     { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
     { l_knuthshuffle_ \int_to_arabic:n \l_knuthshuffle_random_int _element_tl }
    \tl_set_eq:cN { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
     \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
    \tl_set_eq:cN { l_knuthshuffle_ \int_to_arabic:n \l_knuthshuffle_random_int _element_tl }
     \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nv \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
   }
%  \seq_show:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq % for debugging
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\generatepermutation{20}

\[
\printpermutation
\]

\end{document}
```

The values are stored in an associative array using an array of token list variables, which makes addressing fast, at the expense of memory usage.

[image]

---

The same in Plain TeX:

```
\input random
\newcount\myrandom
\newcount\tempcount

\def\generatepermutation#1{%
  \def\lastlength{#1}%
  \tempcount=0
  \loop\ifnum\tempcount<#1\relax
    \advance\tempcount 1
    \expandafter\edef\csname shuffle\the\tempcount element\endcsname{\the\tempcount}%
  \repeat
  \loop\ifnum\tempcount>1
    \setrannum\myrandom{1}{\tempcount}
    \edef\tempa{\csname shuffle\the\tempcount element\endcsname}%
    \edef\tempb{\csname shuffle\the\myrandom element\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\edef\csname shuffle\the\tempcount element\endcsname{\tempb}%
    \expandafter\edef\csname shuffle\the\myrandom element\endcsname{\tempa}%
    \advance\tempcount -1
  \repeat
}

\long\def\gobble#1{}

\def\printpermutation{%
  \left(
  \def\tempa{\gobble}%
  \def\tempb{\gobble}%
  \tempcount=0
  \loop\ifnum\tempcount<\lastlength
    \advance\tempcount 1
    \edef\tempa{\tempa & \the\tempcount}%
    \edef\tempb{\tempb & \csname shuffle\the\tempcount element\endcsname}%
  \repeat
  \vcenter{\tabskip=3pt\halign{&\hfil##\hfil\cr\tempa\cr\tempb\cr}}
  \right)
}

\generatepermutation{20}

$$
\printpermutation
$$

\bye
```

Comment: Damn! I really need to get up to speed with `expl3`!

Comment: @Jubobs It's slow, of course; generating 100 random permutations on 100 numbers requires, on my machine, about 40 seconds.

Comment: @Jubobs If I decrease the size of the “identity property list” to 100, processing is much faster.

Comment: @egreg Probably a case where a 'classical' TeX array might help (still an open question in my mind about the 'back end' for property lists).

Comment: @JosephWright Probably, but I took this as a toy problem. The bottleneck is exactly in efficiently managing the swaps; with a named array it would be much faster, but it would waste a big chunk of memory space.

Comment: @JosephWright I added the more efficient solution as you suggested.

Comment: @egreg I guessed it was more of a toy/demo. Like I said, a question for me/the team is how best to optimise 'behind the scenes'. (One for Bruno, really, and the trouble is it's partly use-case related.)

Comment: @JosephWright Changed to more properly use token lists (which is the same, but with `V` and `v` trickery is even better).

Comment: @egreg Thank Morten for that particular feature!

Comment: Is there a reason for using `\tl_set:cV` instead of `\tl_set_eq:cN`?

Comment: @Manuel No. `;-)` Thanks for noting.

Comment: @egreg I didn't see that you actually used `\tl_set_eq` for two of them. In any case, what's the use case of `\tl_set:NV`? I mean shouldn't we use always `\tl_set_eq:NN` instead? May be something like `\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_int` (just an example of mixing different types)?

Comment: @Manuel `\tl_set:NV` has its uses if the variable is not a token list; it could be an integer variable, for instance, or a clist.