# Randomly sampling a text file in a TeX document (specifically `exam`)

Tags: exam, random

Is there a way to sample random items from a series of text files and include them in `exam` questions?

## Context

I want to create vocab quizzes that comprise a random subset of the words the students have learned. So then I could test them on lists 1-2, or 1-6, or whatever, and not have to make up new quizzes manually (e.g., if I want to give different versions of the quiz to different sections of the same course).

The Cadillac version of this would also sample the definitions and generate a multiple-choice quiz, but I'm saving that for later. For starters, I just want to sample the terms and generate a list of short-answer questions.

## No MWE

There is no MWE yet because I don't know where to start working on this problem. *If* it can be done, what packages or commands should I familiarize myself with to put it together?

Comment: You may add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) without random choice, just to help us with a base to start with, thank you!

Comment: Related: [Assignments and Examinations](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/exams.shtml) (particularly the `probsoln` and `datatool` sections).

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  It is easier if the data is already stored in a TikZ array or comma (for example) delimited string for xstring.  Personally I would use a C++ program to handle the random stuff and use LaTeX to do the formatting.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?s=2|0.0709#346285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following some of the leads offered above in the comments, I have a basic solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{probsoln}

\begin{document}

    \loadrandomproblems{5}{prob_set_1.tex}


    \begin{questions}
    \foreachproblem{\question[1]\thisproblem\dotfill}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```