# How to randomise the order of macros?

Tags: random, questionnaire

I'm designing a questionnaire. I would like to do two things in particular in this design. I'm asking about both things in one question since I believe they are related:

First, I would like to have a random order for the items of the questionnaire. This part, I naively called \randomize in my WME (it's not actually working).

Second, I would like to call different names from my pool of names for the entire questionnaire. I don't know where to begin putting this into code.

Any randomising code I have looked at so far doesn't seems to be doing what I need. One of the more prominent reasons is that I would like to have maximum flexibility and be able to add sentences (and names) as I please.

Any help will be much appreciated – thanks a lot in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\NAMEi}{Sally}
\newcommand{\NAMEii}{Harry}
\newcommand{\NAMEiii}{Anne}
\newcommand{\NAMEiv}{Rob}

\newcommand{\SENTi}{When did \NAMEii \ meet \NAMEi ?}
\newcommand{\SENTii}{What did \NAMEiii \ call \NAMEi ?}
\newcommand{\SENTiii}{Does \NAMEiv \ like haning out with \NAMEi ?}

\begin{document}

\randomize{
\SENTi,\SENTii,\SENTiii
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't combine numbers and letters in a macro unless you use \csname ...\endcsname.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?s=4|12.4425#346285 for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But those are roman numbers which are made out of letters?!

Comment: Ah, so they are.  One can still use `\@roman` to convert.

Comment: @Johnkormylo - Yes, those are roman number, i.e. letters, which works just fine and I did that exactly for the reason that I cannot use numbers in macros.

Answer (score 2):

According to the manual, the random seed (see `\pgfmathsetseed`) defaults to time*year (although `\time*\year` is too large for `\pgfmathparse`).  That means that the seed will change at most once every minute.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcommand{\NAMEi}{Sally}
\newcommand{\NAMEii}{Harry}
\newcommand{\NAMEiii}{Anne}
\newcommand{\NAMEiv}{Rob}

\newcommand{\SENTi}{When did \NAMEii \ meet \NAMEi ?}
\newcommand{\SENTii}{What did \NAMEiii \ call \NAMEi ?}
\newcommand{\SENTiii}{Does \NAMEiv \ like hanging out with \NAMEi ?}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\randomize}[2]% #1=text part of csname, #2=number in list
{\bgroup% use local registers & definitions
  \count1=1
  \loop\ifnum\count1<#2
    \pgfmathparse{int(random(\the\count1,#2))}%
    \count2=\pgfmathresult\relax
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempa\csname #1\@roman\count1\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\tempb\csname #1\@roman\count2\endcsname
    \global\expandafter\let\csname #1\@roman\count1\endcsname=\tempb
    \global\expandafter\let\csname #1\@roman\count2\endcsname=\tempa
    \advance\count1 by 1
  \repeat
\egroup}%
\makeatother

%\AtBeginDocument{\pgfmathsetseed{\time}}% doesn't seem to change

\begin{document}

\randomize{SENT}{3}

\SENTi

\SENTii

\SENTiii

\end{document}
```