# switch string/commands based on "random" values to produce random cards

Tags: conditionals, expl3, xparse, random-numbers, random

**Update**

Or is there a way to generate random number between 1 and 52 using `lcg` package, then associate it to one of the 52 cards from the `pst-poker` package. Which might be easier to achieve?

**OP**

Basically, I want to write something simple for generating random poker cards. It looks like I need `expl3,xparse` and `lcg` (random numbers). But I am not sure how to put them together.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}                %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}       %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage{pst-poker}

%%%%%%%%%%% random %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{lcg} % random number generator
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}

\Ks\tenh\sevd

\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

This would produce some cards nicely for my purpose using `pdflatex`. Now I want to do something like a random card drawing.

The "random" process would be something like this

```
\reinitrand[first=1, last=100, counter=rand]
\rand\arabic{rand}
\reinitrand[first=1, last=13, counter=rand2]
\rand\arabic{rand2}
```

Then to "pick" the card suit, I would do `rand Mod 4`, so the values would be 0,1,2,3, and then I can assign the suits(strings) `s/c/h/d`, for spade,club,heart,dimond.

For `rand2`, it would be cards from `A` to `K` as defined in the package `pst-poker-doc`.

Lastly, putting the two strings togeher to generate keys like `\Ks\tenh\sevd\Kc` ect ...

I am sure there is an easier way to do this, but that's as far as I can go...

Comment: What you want is a random sort.   See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432272/how-to-randomise-the-order-of-macros for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't really want a `shuffle` of the cards, I kind of just want to draw one/two or some of the cards ...

Comment: If you don't want to draw two aces of spades, you need a sort,. Or at least a partal sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation with `expl3`.

A “new” random integer between 13 and 64 is generated and converted to base 13, so we can use the first digit for the suit (from 1 to 4 are clubs, diamonds, hearts and spades) and the second digit for the rank (0 is ace, 1 is two and so on, a is Jack, b is Queen and c is King).

A generated integer is checked to not be among the previously generated ones (if it is a new random integer is cast and the check is performed again). Finally, the card is generated based on the two digits.

```latex
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\generatecards}{m}
 {% #1 = number of cards to generate
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > 52 }
   {% don't generate more than 52 cards
    \casperyc_cards_generate:n { 52 }
   }
   {
    \casperyc_cards_generate:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__casperyc_cards_used_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \casperyc_cards_generate:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__casperyc_cards_used_seq
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \casperyc_cards_randomcard: }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \casperyc_cards_randomcard:
 {
  \__casperyc_cards_format:e { \int_to_base:nn { \int_rand:nn { 13 } { 64 } } { 13 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__casperyc_cards_format:n
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \l__casperyc_cards_used_seq { #1 }
   {% already used card, redo
    \casperyc_cards_randomcard:
   }
   {% new card
    % add to the list of used cards
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__casperyc_cards_used_seq { #1 }
    % format it
    \__casperyc_cards_format:nn #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__casperyc_cards_format:n { e }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__casperyc_cards_format:nn
 {
  \use:c
   {
    \__casperyc_cards_rank:n { #2 }
    \__casperyc_cards_seed:n { #1 }
   }~
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__casperyc_cards_seed:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {1}{c}
    {2}{d}
    {3}{h}
    {4}{s}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__casperyc_cards_rank:n
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1 }
   {
    {0}{A}
    {1}{two}
    {2}{tre}
    {3}{four}
    {4}{five}
    {5}{six}
    {6}{sev}
    {7}{eig}
    {8}{nine}
    {9}{ten}
    {a}{J}
    {b}{Q}
    {c}{K}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\generatecards{20}

\bigskip

\generatecards{52}

\bigskip

\generatecards{200}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly using `latex`. Is there a way to switch this to `pdflatex` so I can put this to my original file and compile with the `pdflatex -shell-escape` option? I have tried the normal `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` option, but it didn't seem to be working. Thanks again.

Comment: @CasperYC No idea, but I suspect an unrelated issue deeper than just this problem. The `-pics` PDF file is correctly generated, as far as I can see.

Comment: I will look for more help on SE. Thanks anyway. BTW, is the `expl3` still experimental? I read it somewhere last night, it was designed for, so that `tex` is more programmerable? I code in a lot of mathematical programmes, but since I don't really `code` in LaTeX that much, is it useful to learn these lines between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` now? Are they kind of transferrable in the future for `latex3` project?

Comment: @CasperYC A good deal of it is included in the LaTeX kernel, nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from `Andrews' answer from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfJ39.png).

It works well as far as the OP is concerned, but it can not be used in `fancyhead` as a footer or header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}                %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}       %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage{pst-poker}
\psset{inline=card}  %symbol/boxed

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%% random %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor} % needed only for the examples
\usepackage{xparse}
%
% \DefineRandomSequence{<sequence>}: random elements with repeats
% \DefineRandomSequence*{<sequence>}: random elements without repeats
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineRandomSequence{sm}{%
    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\time}% set a "random" seed based on time
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{myrandomlist}{#2}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\let\pgfsequencegenerator\pgfmathrandomitemwithoutreplacement}
                    {\let\pgfsequencegenerator\pgfmathrandomitem}
}
% \myitem: print random element of sequence
\newcommand\myitem{\pgfsequencegenerator\randomitem{myrandomlist}\randomitem}

\makeatletter
% Mark Wibrow: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113987/how-do-i-generate-in-latex-a-list-of-random-questions-avoiding-repetitions
\def\pgfmathrandomitemwithoutreplacement#1#2{%
    \pgfmath@ifundefined{pgfmath@randomlist@#2}{\pgfmath@error{Unknown random list `#2'}}{%
        \edef\pgfmath@randomlistlength{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2\endcsname}%
        \ifnum\pgfmath@randomlistlength>0\relax%
            \pgfmathrandominteger{\pgfmath@randomtemp}{1}{\pgfmath@randomlistlength}%
            \def\pgfmath@marshal{\def#1}%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfmath@marshal\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@\pgfmath@randomtemp\endcsname}%
            % Now prune.
            \c@pgfmath@counta=\pgfmath@randomtemp\relax%
            \c@pgfmath@countb=\c@pgfmath@counta%
            \advance\c@pgfmath@countb by1\relax%
            \pgfmathloop%
            \ifnum\c@pgfmath@counta=\pgfmath@randomlistlength\relax%
            \else%
                \def\pgfmath@marshal{\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@\the\c@pgfmath@counta\endcsname=}%
                \expandafter\pgfmath@marshal\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2@\the\c@pgfmath@countb\endcsname%
                \advance\c@pgfmath@counta by1\relax%
                \advance\c@pgfmath@countb by1\relax%
            \repeatpgfmathloop%
            \advance\c@pgfmath@counta by-1\relax%
            \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#2\endcsname{\the\c@pgfmath@counta}%
        \else%
            \pgfmath@error{Random list `#2' is empty}%
        \fi%
    }}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{postscript}
%%
%%
%%
\pagestyle{empty}

% \DefineRandomSequence
\DefineRandomSequence*{{\As} {\Ah} {\Ad} {\Ac} {\Ks} {\Kh} {\Kd} {\Kc} {\Qs} {\Qh} {\Qd} {\Qc} {\Js} {\Jh} {\Jd} {\Jc} {\tens} {\tenh} {\tend} {\tenc} {\nines} {\nineh} {\nined} {\ninec} {\eigs} {\eigh} {\eigd} {\eigc} {\sevs} {\sevh} {\sevd} {\sevc} {\sixs} {\sixh} {\sixd} {\sixc} {\fives} {\fiveh} {\fived} {\fivec} {\fours} {\fourh} {\fourd} {\fourc} {\tres} {\treh} {\tred} {\trec} {\twos} {\twoh} {\twod} {\twoc}}


\foreach \x in {1,...,4}{\myitem\space}
\foreach \y in {1,...,8}{\myitem\space}
\foreach \z in {1,...,20}{\myitem\space}
\foreach \a in {1,...,52}{\myitem\space}



\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

Worked fine with shorter lists (<52).

[image]

Or with 52 cards exactly

[image]

But won't work if you put all of them together

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}{\myitem\space}

\foreach \y in {1,...,8}{\myitem\space}

\foreach \z in {1,...,20}{\myitem\space}

\foreach \a in {1,...,52}{\myitem\space}
```

gives

[image]

For my purpose, this is good enough except that it doesn't work in `fancyhead`. It does work as intended as far as the question is concerned. So I am posting it as an answer.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\foreach \x in {1,...,4}{\myitem\space} }
\lipsum[3-9]
\lipsum[4-20]
```

[image]