# Random shuffle multiple choice questions and options

Tags: lists, random

I have the following enumerate list

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item question 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
        \item option 3
        \item option 4
    \end{enumerate}

    \item question 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
        \item option 3
        \item option 4
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

I am thinking of randomizing both the orders of questions and options. I tried using `randomlist` package, and it works perfectly if I only shuffled the order of the questions as follows:

```
\RandomEnumerateList
{question 1
\begin{enumerate}
    \item option 1
    \item option 2
    \item option 3
    \item option 4
\end{enumerate}
}
{question 2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item option 1
    \item option 2
    \item option 3
    \item option 4
\end{enumerate}
}
```

But it seems not to work when putting another `\RandomEnumerateList` in a `\RandomEnumerateList`. Is there any way I can tweak my current script to shuffle both the orders of questions and options at the same time?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432272/how-to-randomise-the-order-of-macros

Answer (score 0):

After a quick try with randomlist, I don’t know whether it’s possible to nest lists with it. [Here is a quick proof-of-concept](https://github.com/jperon/randenum) to do that with LuaLaTeX. After copying [randenum.lua](https://github.com/jperon/randenum/raw/master/randenum.lua) and [randenum.sty](https://github.com/jperon/randenum/raw/master/randenum.sty) within your project directory, the following `document.tex` should give the expected result:

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{randenum}

\begin{document}

\begin{randenum}
    \item question 1
    \begin{randenum}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
        \item option 3
        \item option 4
    \end{randenum}

    \item question 2
    \begin{randenum}
        \item option 1
        \item option 2
        \item option 3
        \item option 4
    \end{randenum}
\end{randenum}

\end{document}
```

Then compile *with LuaLaTeX*: `lualatex document`

Caution: there are some caveats with the approach I took:

- `\begin{randenum}` and `\end{randenum}` must be on their own line;
- the `randenum` environment can’t be easily wrapped within another environment.