# Generate an iterable list

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, lists

I need to return an iterable list (that will be used in another steps) from an previous list that includes expandable content (variables and math operations).

```
\def \scale {1} 
\pgfmathparse{\scale * 0.6}\edef\hc{\pgfmathresult}
%morphology coordinates x,y,..
\newcommand*{\xMorph}{0,0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0, \hc*0.5,-\hc*0.5,0,0,0, -\effdepth*0.5}
```

The approach that was used include an intermediate step for expand the list, but after the process the list isn´t iterable as is requested to it.

```
%expand aux func
\newcommand*{\expandlist}[1]{%
\edef\resultado{}
\foreach \i [remember=\i as \li (initially 0), evaluate=\i as \r using \i+\li]in {#1}{  
     \resultado{ \resultado \r}%
    }
}
```

A simple test, like a for loop to obtain a single element one at time,

```
\begin{document}
%first case
\xMorph
%second case
\expandafter\def\expandafter\xLp\expandafter{\expandlist{\xMorph}}
\xLp
%third case
\foreach \k [count=\cn] in {\xLp}{\cn}
```

From the previus code, the results are: first one is the list without expansion (wrong), the second one is the list expanded but as a single element (1) as it shown in the count variable (\cn) derived from the for-loop.

```
0,0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0, 0.6*0.5,-0.6*0.5,0,0,0, -0.5*0.5   000000000.3-0.3000-0.25 1
```

any ideas will be well received.

Comment: `\expandlist` is not expandable, as it starts with `\def`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. Totally agree with you, my mistake; but after the change the result is the same.

Comment: It seems necessary to understand what you're really after: can you give an example of the expected output?

Comment: Ok. I need an iterable list like `\foreach \k [count=\cn] in {4,5,6}{\cn}` with a output: `123`

Comment: If you just want this output, you could simply do `\xdef\mylst{}
\foreach \k [count=\cn] in {4,5,6}{\xdef\mylst{\mylst\cn}}`. I guess there is more to the story, isn't it?

Comment: The best way to implement a storage array is to use \csname ...\endcsname.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?s=2|14.4647#346285 for example.

Comment: Thanks @marmot, and yes indeed. What i want to say was that the desired output was a iterable element, exemplified as the count number iterable  `\cn`. But the main goal is that i can make a `list={a+b+c, d*0.5+4...}` that cointains some algebraic expression inside and need to be "evaluate" (like \evaluate\list={} ... output: {1, 3.443, ....}) keeping the iterability before to pass to another function (foreach \i in {\list}{ \code}) . The final goal is obtain a list with variables and algebraic operations that can be modify.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this in general, but I am sure @egreg does. However, this sounds a little bit as if you were interested in `tikzmath`. There you will be able to define recursive relations and so on, just look for "Fibonacci" in the pgfmanual. Ti*k*Z also allows you to build and parse arrays.

Comment: See `listofitems` package for absorbing a list that can be regurgitated at will.  If you were to put together a complete MWE, rather than just code snippets, I might be able to do something with it.