# Random sorting of text items

Tags: itemize, sorting, random

I would like to produce random texts in which some specific
items would be sorted and printed in a random order, varying at each compilation.
The intended purpose is to remove any hidden bias in the way the list is constructed. I have looked for a ready to use package or solution, but did not find any.

More specifically, I am working on the basis of something like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\newcommand{\tobesorted}{}
\newenvironment{sortingitems}{}{}
\begin{document}
In my farm there are:
\begin{sortingitems}
\tobesorted pigs,
\tobesorted cows,
\tobesorted rabbits,
\tobesorted gnus,
\end{sortingitems}
and they all live in perfect harmony.
\end{document}
```

which would print the list of animals in a random order that would vary at each compilation. In my intended application, I would have several a few hundreds short items to be sorted. For the moment, I do not care much about punctuation at the end of the last item (but I am also interested).

Comment: Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX to compile your document?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order

Comment: @Mico Yes indeed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Quite nice also. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the built-in `\seq_shuffle:N` command from the kernel to shuffle items and then use `\seq_map_inline:Nn` to map the items to your list.

Here's a version that puts everything into a single command. If you prefer you could make the command just do the shuffling and mapping and insert that command inside each list environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_denis_shuffle_items_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\shuffleitems}{m}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_denis_shuffle_items_seq {#1}
    \seq_shuffle:N \l_denis_shuffle_items_seq
    \begin{enumerate}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_denis_shuffle_items_seq {\item ##1}
    \end{enumerate}
} 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\shuffleitems{pigs, cows,rabbits,gnus}
\end{document}
```

[image: possible output of code]

In your specific use case, if you want the enumerated items as a comma separated list inserted in running text rather than an enumeration, you can use the `\seq_use:Nnnn` macro to do that. This is a very nice macro which takes a sequence and then 3 arguments corresponding to the elements you want between 2, more than two, and the final 2 elements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_denis_shuffle_questions_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\shuffleitems}{m}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_denis_shuffle_questions_seq {#1}
    \seq_shuffle:N \l_denis_shuffle_questions_seq
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l_denis_shuffle_questions_seq {~and~}{,~}{,~and~}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
The \shuffleitems{pigs, cows,rabbits,gnus} all live in perfect harmony.
\end{document}
```

[image: possible output of second example]

Comment: Your solution is very elegant. Will test it more extensively. But thanks a lot for the very nice solution.

Comment: @Denis I've added a version that is closer to your actual use case.

Comment: I can't help thinking TeX is not the easiest solution!

Comment: @cfr I don't know, this is pretty simple! It would definitely depend on the use case. I have a problem set that randomizes 5 macros using `lua` code, and it's more complicated than this. So much so that I'll probably rewrite it using this method. But I'm not going to have TeX randomize my experimental stimuli... :)

Comment: I suppose it's just that I've never done it this way. It seems a lot of bother, I guess.

Comment: @AlanMunn The new addition makes the solution quite flexible. It suits my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A way using knitr:

[image: MWE]

`MWE.Rnw` (Rstudio) or `MWE.Rtex` (Overleaf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,>>=
v <- c("pigs","cows","rabbits","gnus")
@
\begin{itemize} 
\item I have \Sexpr{combine_words(sample(v))}
\item You have \Sexpr{combine_words(sample(v))}
\item He has \Sexpr{combine_words(sample(v))}
\item We have  
<<foo, echo=F,results='asis'>>=
cat("\\begin{itemize}\\item ")
cat(sample(v), sep="\n\\item ")
cat("\\end{itemize} ")
@
\item They have  
<<morefoo, echo=F,results='asis'>>=
<<foo>>
@
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also nice using a different path. Thanks for this.