How can I transpose a matrix A using tmp
I have the following MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\tikzmath{
    \n=6;
    int \i;
    for \i in {0,...,\n}{
        \x{\i} = \i; 
        \y{\i} = sin(\i r);
        \z{\i} = cos(\i r);
    }; 
}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill}%
\edef\k{0}%
\loop
\xappto\tmp{$\k$ & $\x{\k}$&  $\y{\k}$ & $\z{\k}$ }%
\edef\k{\the\numexpr\k+1}%
\gappto\tmp{\\}%
\ifnum\k<\fpeval{\n+1}\repeat


Consider the matrix:\\

$A = \left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
    \tmp
\end{array}
\right]
$\\

How can I write the transpose of $A$? A code for:\\

$A = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 &5 & 6\\
\ldots&\\
\end{array}
\right]
$\\


\end{document}


whose output is the following:

Then I define \n and build the values of x and y using tikzmath . Then, I use the code
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=4,zerofill}%
\edef\k{0}%
\loop
\xappto\tmp{$\k$ & $\x{\k}$&  $\y{\k}$ & $\z{\k}$ }%
\edef\k{\the\numexpr\k+1}%
\gappto\tmp{\\}%
\ifnum\k<\fpeval{\n+1}\repeat

to build the matrix iteratively line per line. Woks very well.
However, if I want to build the matrix per columns using this resource (not manually), e.g, how can I build the transpose of this matrix using \tmp environment? Is there a way to transpose these matrix?

pgfplotstable can generate a transpose, if it is already in pgfplotstable format.  You might also look into using \csname arrays instead of pgfmath arrays.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346260/display-item-list-in-sequential-and-random-without-repetition-order/346285?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.0267#346285 for example.
