# Random Page Numbers

Tags: page-numbering, random-numbers

I need some help with a crazy idea. For a book I want the page numbers to be a random permutation. As an example, if the book would have 5 pages, I want something like (4,1,2,5,3). Optimally, the table of contents and references would work. I don't know enough about TeX to do it myself. I am already happy about some directions in how to proceed.

I use the book LaTeX class and XeLatex.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which TeX engine do you use (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`) and would it bother you to switch?

Comment: I use xelatex. yes, i would consider switching if that makes the solution much easier. you thinking about lua?

Comment: off topic: i tried felt 5 times to write 'dear tex community' at the beginning of my post, but it always deletes that line. very strange. is the stack overflow editor broken?

Comment: @EmanResu I do not know why it is deleted, but you do not need to write 'dear tex community', 'thank you', etc.

Comment: Do you know how many pages you have? With that it is easier to construct a function that does the permutation, and put that in the page number.

Comment: @Karlo Perhaps there is in automated friendliness deletion algorithm in place ;)

Comment: @StefanH Yes, I know how many pages

Comment: @EmanResu See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989 .

Comment: As answered below, it is quite possible. However: If your book is something long, and is going to be commercially printed, then the printing service will disallow that. The reason is that it will confuse persons who inspect the finished book for quality assurance.

Comment: @RobtA The goal is to confuse people ;)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The automated friendliness deletion algorithm is indeed in place ;)

Comment: Gosh, if the goal is to confuse people, then all you have do do is let them read the TeX source document.

Comment: @RobtA There are multiple ways to confuse people. And some are funnier than others.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This uses the specified permutation within range, if you have more pages than that it reverts to normal, so you can always modify the definition at the end once you know how many pages you have

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand\thepage{%
\ifcase\value{page}%
0\or
4\or
1\or
2\or
5\or
6\or
3\else
\arabic{page}%
\fi}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\section{Zzzz}aaaa
\section{Zzzzz}aaaa \clearpage bbbb
\section{Zzzzz}aaaa


\chapter{Something}
\section{Zzzz zzz}aaaa
\section{Zzzzzz zzz}aaaa \clearpage bbbb
\section{Zzzzzzz zzz}aaaa


\end{document}
```

Comment: No fancy expl3 solution? I'm really disappointed.

Comment: @TeXnician I need to leave an opening for egreg to try to steal a tick.

Comment: that should work. i have like 170 pages, so will generate the beginning with python and paste it in the tex code.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun an implementation that doesn't require external programs and just needs two LaTeX runs. However, the pages will change at every subsequent run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-abspage,atveryend}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Coerce zref into not adding the last page number in the .aux file
% which would always issue the warning that labels have changed
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{lastabs}
\zref@addprop{lastabs}{abspage}
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \advance\c@page\m@ne
      \toks@\expandafter{\Z@L@lastabs}%
      \expandafter\zref@wrapper@immediate\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\ZREF@label\expandafter{\the\toks@}{LastAbsPage}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:Nc \zref_extract:nn { zref@extract }

% a variant of the Knuth shuffle algorithm as implemented
% in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224559/4427

\cs_new:Nn \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn
 {
  \int_set:Nn #1 { \fp_eval:n { randint(#2,#3) } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
\int_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_random_int
\prop_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop
\prop_new:N \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop % the identity
\seq_new:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n
 {
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { -1 } { 2 }
   {
    \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \l_knuthshuffle_random_int { 1 } { ##1 }
    \prop_get:NnN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl 
    \prop_get:NVN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl 
    \prop_put:NnV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
    \prop_put:NVV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
   }
  \seq_clear:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
     {
      \prop_item:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 }
     }
   }
  %\seq_show:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq % for debugging
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n { x }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \int_compare:nT { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} > 0 }
   {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
     {
      \prop_gput:Nnn \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop { #1 } { #1 }
     }
    \knuthshuffle_generate:n { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\randomarabic{page}}
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomarabic}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { \value{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\kant[1-102]

\ExplSyntaxOn
% for showing the used page numbers
\seq_use:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { ,~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

At the end the sequence of the used page numbers has been added by way of example.

Here's the bottom of the last page.

[image]

A more complex strategy can cope also with the table of contents. Now the random sequence is only computed if the number of pages has changed since the last LaTeX run, otherwise the previous sequence is used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{zref-abspage,atveryend}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{lastabs}
\zref@addprop{lastabs}{abspage}
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \begingroup
      \advance\c@page\m@ne
      \toks@\expandafter{\Z@L@lastabs}%
      \expandafter\zref@wrapper@immediate\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\ZREF@label\expandafter{\the\toks@}{LastAbsPage}%
      }%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:Nc \zref_extract:nn { zref@extract }

\cs_new:Nn \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn
 {
  \int_set:Nn #1 { \fp_eval:n { randint(#2,#3) } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
\int_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_random_int
\prop_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop
\prop_new:N \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop % the identity
\seq_new:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n
 {
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { -1 } { 2 }
   {
    \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \l_knuthshuffle_random_int { 1 } { ##1 }
    \prop_get:NnN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl 
    \prop_get:NVN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl 
    \prop_put:NnV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 } \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
    \prop_put:NVV \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \l_knuthshuffle_random_int \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
   }
  \seq_clear:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
     {
      \prop_item:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop { ##1 }
     }
   }
  %\seq_show:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq % for debugging
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n { x }

\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \seq_if_empty:NT \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
   {
    \int_compare:nT { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} > 0 }
     {
      \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
       {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop { #1 } { #1 }
       }
      \knuthshuffle_generate:n { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
     }
   }
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\randomarabic{page}}
 }

\AfterLastShipout
 {
  \int_compare:nT { \value{abspage} = \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
   {
    \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
     {
      \randompagesequence
       { \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
       { \seq_use:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { , } }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \randompagesequence #1 #2
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 = \zref_extract:nn {LastAbsPage}{abspage} }
   {
    \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { #2 }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\randomarabic}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { \value{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_show:N \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tableofcontents

\section{One}
\kant[1-20]
\section{Two}
\kant[21-30]
\section{Three}
\kant[31-53]

\ExplSyntaxOn
% for showing the used page numbers
\seq_use:Nn \g_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { ,~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yay for the Knuth shuffle! (Obligatory link to the blog http://tex-talk.net/2011/08/do-the-knuth-shuffle/ though I note that the formatting is all messed up)

Answer (score 5):

Well, just to play around with it: A solution with `expl3` with the only drawback that it will not check for an existing page with that number. The max page number can be set in `\l__blob_int`.

[image: random]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__quack_clist
\int_new:N \l__blub_int
\int_gset:Nn \l__blub_int {0}
\int_new:N \l__blob_int
\int_gset:Nn \l__blob_int {10}
\int_do_while:nn {\l__blub_int < \l__blob_int}
    {
        \clist_put_right:NV \l__quack_clist \l__blub_int
        \int_incr:N \l__blub_int
    }
\renewcommand\thepage{%
    \clist_item:Nn \l__quack_clist {\fp_eval:n {randint(\clist_count:N\l__quack_clist)}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}
\section{Zzzz}aaaa
\section{Zzzzz}aaaa \clearpage bbbb
\section{Zzzzz}aaaa


\chapter{Something}
\section{Zzzz zzz}aaaa
\section{Zzzzzz zzz}aaaa \clearpage bbbb
\section{Zzzzzzz zzz}aaaa


\end{document}
```